# OpenLDAP: pwdChangedTime attribute isn't created after changing the password?

Tags: ldap, centos5, openldap, password-policy

I'm going to integrate the [check_mk's Multisite with OpenLDAP](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_multisite_ldap_integration.html). After configuring the LDAP connector, I get the following error when opening the "Users & Contacts" page:

```
Error executing sync hook
The "Authentication Expiration" attribute (pwdchangedtime) could not
be fetchedfrom the LDAP server for user {u'cn': [u'noreply']}.
```

Here're all the steps that I've done to implement the Password Policy Overlay:

Install overlay modules for OpenLDAP server:

```
yum install openldap-servers-overlays
```

Add the following lines to /etc/openldap/slapd.conf:

```
include     /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

modulepath  /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload  ppolicy.la
```

then I restart the OpenLDAP and try to change the password. I'm sure it's changed successfully but I don't see the `pwdChangedTime` attribute when running a `ldapsearch`:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" -y .passwd.cnf "cn=noreply"
dn: cn=noreply,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: noreply
mail: noreply at domain.com
maildrop: noreply at domain.com
sn: No
uid: noreply
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: mailUser
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: pwdPolicyChecker
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 31536000
pwdMinAge: 60
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
userPassword: {MD5}xx
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the `pwdChangedTime` attribute is already created but since it 
is an [operational attribute](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/#operational), it is not returned by default.
You have to do a `ldapsearch` with this name:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" -W "cn=noreply"
pwdChangedTime
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=noreply
# requesting: pwdChangedTime
#

# noreply, it, domain.com
dn: cn=noreply,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
pwdChangedTime: 20130128154849Z
```

or append the plus (`+`) to the `ldapsearch`:

```
# ldapsearch -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" -y .passwd.cnf "cn=noreply" +
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=noreply
# requesting: + 
#

# noreply, it, domain.com
dn: cn=noreply,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: 047e7ce6-3b99-1031-83cb-afef2344189c
creatorsName: cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com
createTimestamp: 20120526161012Z
pwdChangedTime: 20130129032710Z
entryCSN: 20130129032710Z#00003a#00#000000
modifiersName: cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com
modifyTimestamp: 20130129032710Z
entryDN: cn=noreply,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: FALSE
```

To add this attribute to the all users which are created before 
implementing Password Policy Overlay, you can simply update the `userPassword` with the same value:

```
ldapsearch -x -D cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com -W -y .passwd.txt -L
"(&(objectclass=person)(!(pwdChangedTime=*)))" userPassword
     | sed '/dn: /a\changetype: modify\nreplace: userPassword'
         | ldapmodify -x -D cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com -y .passwd.txt -W
```